# Java - Open command prompt, run two commands

Tags: java, command-prompt

Noobish question I'm sure, but I'm trying to open a command prompt, switch to a directory, then run a second command. I've got:

```
try {
// Execute command
String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

// Get output stream to write from it
OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();

out.write("cd C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Reports\Scripts   /r/n".getBytes());
out.flush();
out.write("for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> Export.txt /r/n".getBytes());
out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

My ignorant guess is the **"%f"** in the second command needs to be written properly, but I know so little about java I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes, write `"%f"` as `\"%f\"`

Comment: How much do you know about string escaping in Java (and other languages with C-derived syntax)?

Comment: @ immibis: Who lot of zero. Do a lot of VBA for work and trying to venture into java.

Comment: @Titus: Okay, yeah I needed to know that. Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...") to run command lines, and you can use "&&" to execute more than one command, e.g.:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"start something.bat && start somethingelse.bat \"");
```

Comment: Hmm okay I tried Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"cd C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Reports\Scripts && for %f in (*.txt) do type \"%f\" >> Export.txt \"");      Do I need anything before or after that?